# nodeschool cant run lesson from anywhere on terminal

Tags: node.js, path

I finished the first lesson for [nodeschool](http://nodeschool.io/)

to run the "javascripting" lesson, i just type

> $javascripting

on console,

but when installed other lesson "learnyounode"

> $sudo npm install --global learnyounode

seems to install ok,
but when i type

> $learnyounode

I get,

> -bash: learnyounode: command not found

I can see that the module is in `/Users/iosdev/npm-global/lib/node_modules`

so I how to add this "module" so I can start from anywhere on CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding that path you mentioned to your bash_profile. 
cd into your home directory and find this file .bash_profile and look for the line with

```
export PATH=
```

and add your path to look like like:

```
export PATH="/Users/iosdev/npm-global/lib/node_modules:$PATH"
```

or you just run the above command on your terminal directly.

This will append 'this' path so that bash understands each node module.
Normally your global node modules are installed at `/usr/local/bin`, and you may see `/usr/local/bin` already part of the $PATH environment variable.
I installed the module globally as mentioned in your link and i can access it on any directory.